# Why uploading sql file to mysql database with phpmyadmin import or bigdump doesn't use CPU time but is damn slow

Tags: mysql, import

Exactly as the title says, I found no reason and I cannot figure out myself why importing sql files to a mysql database on a local ethernet network is so damn slow even for files of only 4MB and yet the CPU usage is around 1% and memory even less..

I get the above results by uploading a sql file of 4MB with bigdump and then issuing a

```
  top
```

command on the remote host: while the import is working the process is using 1% of CPU.
So what is exactly doing the computer all that time?

**EDIT**: even avoiding the network at all by using simply a local file import with a command like

```
  mysql -u root -ppassword database_name < database.sql
```

takes forever and yet memory and cpu are very low in usage..

Thank you

Comment: What id your disk IO?

Comment: what is my disk IO? I don't know but 4MB is so little I guess the file is loaded entirely into memory and given to the program.

Comment: If you haven't actually measured it, you are just guessing.

Comment: I'd have to concur with @PieterGeerkens; most write operations (especially bulk ones) are I/O bound, not CPU-bound.  `iostat` is your friend.

Comment: Are you accessing the file over a network? That can turn your DB into a file server, and will kill performance when it happens.

Comment: it is not network related (see my edit where I don't use the network at all). I will try iostat but if it were IO related, that means that for every row it accesses the 4Mb file instead of buffering it to memory.. that sounds like a very silly behaviour..

Answer (score 1):

You haven't offered enough information to give a precise answer to your question.

But there's an excellent chance your MySQL server is I/O bound. You're very likely hammering on your hard-drive storage as you upload your table.

I suspect the table you're importing is an InnoDB table, and that you're doing an implicit commit after each insert. It's also possible you're loading a table that has lots of indexes in it.

Look at this page:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html

You  can try editing the file with your SQL data in it to wrap chunks of roughly 100 `INSERT` statements like this.

```
 START TRANSACTION;
 INSERT ...
   ...
 INSERT ...
 COMMIT;
 START TRANSACTION;
 INSERT ...
   ...
 INSERT ...
 COMMIT;
 START TRANSACTION;
 INSERT ...
   ...
 INSERT ...
 COMMIT;
```

It will reduce the number of transactions and reduce server I/O.

Your table may also have a bunch of keys; you can disable updating those keys for each row and just do it when the upload is done.  This can save tons of time.

Here's an article.

http://support.tigertech.net/mysql-large-inserts

Comment: I use myIsam and don't put any explicit transaction, so I guess Mysql treats every insert as a transaction. I will try creating only an initial transaction and a closing one at the end an see how it behaves. IO bound is unrelated in my opinion because 4Mb is very little and top command would show a high cpu usage also for IO-related operations which pass through the CPU anyway.

Comment: Your instinct about I/O is valid for many kinds of system.  It happens to be incorrect for DBMS work, however.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue while importing mysql dump. Each table having records around 10 was taking approx. 1 minute of time. I managed to speed up this by tweaking mysql.ini file. I modified following values in mysql.ini file:

1. max_allowed_packet = 32M
2. innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32M

Then restart mysql service. Please make sure not to increase more than 50% of total RAM memory.

Answer (score -1):

Enable Remote Access To MySQL Database Server
By default, remote access to the MySQL database server is disabled for security reasons.

Heidisql for Windows or Datagrip for lunix.

For example use Heidisql:

1. Connecting Remotely with Heidi SQL
2. Open Heidi SQL.
3. Click New.
4. Name the connection. Hit the enter key.
5. Enter your connection settings. The settings should be like the following. Network type: MySQL (TCP/IP). ...
6. Click Open. Now you will see the databases and tables on your server.